# How to resolve the issue of start time transformation to 00:00 and the buggy behavior when selecting dates in the provided video link?

Tags: selection, react-big-calendar

Link: https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/issues/2535

Anyone has any idea how to resolve this issue from the video in the link i provided above? When selecting the dates and moving upwards ( even in their examples ) it transforms the start time to 00:00 and looks buggy.

Its an issue present in their examples as well

Tryed pretty much everything i could've come up with, but it seems to be a package problem since it happening in their examples as well